# Selenium SafariDriver doesn't wait for page to load?

Tags: selenium, safaridriver

It appears that the SafariDriver for Selenium doesn't wait for web pages to load. My test is as follows:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class SafariTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new SafariDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGoogleSearch() {
        driver.get("http://duckduckgo.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("search_form_input_homepage")).sendKeys("Hello World");
        driver.findElement(By.id("search_button_homepage")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).click();
    }
}
```

If you run this with `ChromeDriver`, or `FirefoxDriver`, it functions as it should, i.e. it searches for "Hello World", then on the results page, it goes to the image results.

With `SafariDriver`, it fails with:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

The element that could not be found being "Images", since the page hasn't loaded before it ran that statement.

**Is this expected behavior? Am I supposed to special case for Safari?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to account for that with an Explicit Wait with `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);

WebElement images = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Images")));
images.click();
```

Comment: Why would I have to do this _only_ with Safari and no other browser?